# I can't get my php sessions variable to work

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm here because I have a problem in php programming. I want to pass variable from a form to another form and then to send it as an email. But my sessions variables won't work and I don't know why.

You will fin my codes below,also sorry for the quality, I'm just coding for school and the presentation doesn't matter, I just want my code to work. (I'm french by the way so sorry for my bad english).

Payment.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ob_start();?>
<html lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <title> E-COMMERCE </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/ordi.jpg" />
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/bootstrap.min.css?o2e784");
<!--@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/modern-business.css?o2e784");
@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/site_global.css?o2e784");
@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/style.css?o2e784");-->
@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/responsive.css?o2e784");

</style>

<link href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <!-- CLOSE head -->
    </head>
    <a href="deconnexion.php" value="Deconnexion"><img src="image/deconnexion.png" height="35px" width="110px" id="bouton"/></a>
        <br/><br/>
    <center><pre>Les cours d'informatique c'est des barres, ici on t'apprendra à créer des sites presque aussi beaux que celui-ci.</pre></center><br/>
        <p class="flotte">
            <center><a href="http://iut.nice.netspace.fr/g1_tpellero/ProjetSI/accueil.php"><img src="image/logo.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
        </p>
        <p style="line-height:50px;">
            <font size="10pt"> E-COMMERCE </font>
        </p></center>
        <br></br>
<center>        
<p><font size="6pt"> Adresse de Facturation et Livraison </font></p></center><br />
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="adresseFacturation"><br />
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="adresseFacturation"/>
<label>Nom:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus required/></code><br></br>
<label>Prenom:</label>
<input type="text" name="prenom" required/><br></br>
<label>Adresse:</label>
<input type="text" name="adresse" required/></code><br></br>
<label>Code Postal:</label>
<input type="number" name="codepostal" required/></code><br></br>
<label>Ville:</label>
<input type="text" name="ville" required/></code><br></br>
<label>Pays:</label>
<input type="text" name="pays" required/></code><br></br>
<center><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Envoyer" /></center>
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>


<?php
$nom=$_POST['name'];
$prenom=$_POST['prenom'];
$adresse=$_POST['adresse'];
$codepostal=$_POST['codepostal'];
$ville=$_POST['ville'];
$pays=$_POST['pays'];
$compteur=0;

IF (isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    if(!empty($nom)){
        $_SESSION['nom'] = $nom;
    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if(!empty($prenom)){
        $_SESSION['prenom'] = $prenom;
    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if(!empty($adresse)){
        $_SESSION['adresse']=$adresse;
    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if(!empty($codepostal)){
        $_SESSION['codepostal']=$codepostal;
    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if(!empty($ville)){
        $_SESSION['ville']=$ville;
    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if(!empty($pays)){
        $_SESSION['pays']=$pays;

    }else{
        $compteur++;
    }

    if($compteur == 0){
        $_SESSION['adressecomplete']="Nom: ".$_SESSION['nom']."<br></br> Prenom: ".$_SESSION['prenom']."<br></br> Adresse: ".
        $_SESSION['adresse']."<br></br> Code Postal: ".$_SESSION['codepostal']."<br></br> Ville: ".$_SESSION['ville']."<br></br> Pays: ".$_SESSION['pays']."<br></br> Informations complémentaires: ";
    }
}

//echo "Adresse complete : ".$_SESSION['adressecomplete'];
//echo "<br></br> Nom :".$_SESSION['nom'];
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I have to send this informations to contact.php but my sessions variables doesn't work when I try to show them with an echo.

contact.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ob_start();?>
<html lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <title> E-COMMERCE </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/ordi.jpg" />
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/bootstrap.min.css?o2e784");
        <!--@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/modern-business.css?o2e784");
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/site_global.css?o2e784");
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/style.css?o2e784");-->
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/responsive.css?o2e784");

        </style>

<link href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

    <!-- CLOSE head -->
    </head>
    <a href="deconnexion.php" value="Deconnexion"><img src="image/deconnexion.png" height="35px" width="110px" id="bouton"/></a>
        <br/><br/>
    <center><pre>Les cours d'informatique c'est des barres, ici on t'apprendra à créer des sites presque aussi beaux que celui-ci.</pre></center><br/>
        <p class="flotte">
            <center><a href="http://iut.nice.netspace.fr/g1_tpellero/ProjetSI/accueil.php"><img src="image/logo.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
        </p>
        <p style="line-height:50px;">
            <font size="10pt"> E-COMMERCE </font>
        </p></center>
<br></br>
<center>
<p><font size="6pt"> Formulaire de Contact </font></p></center><br />
<form method="post" action="envoie_email.php" id="contact"><br />
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="contact"/>
<label>Nom:</label>
<input type="text" name="nomP" autofocus required /></code><br></br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="mail" style="text-align:center;color:blue" required/></code><br></br>
<label>Objet:</label>
<input type="text" name="objet" required/></code><br></br>
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea COLS=30 ROWS=12 name="comments"></textarea><br></br>
<center><input id="envoie" type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Envoyer" /></center>
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>

<?php 
echo "Adresse complete:   ".$_SESSION['adressecomplete'];
echo "<br>Adresse:   ".$_POST['adresse'];
echo "<br>prenom:   ".$_POST['prenom'];
?>

<?php
$nomP=$_POST['nomP'];
$mail=$_POST['mail'];
$objet=$_POST['objet'];
$message=$_POST['comments'];


IF (isset($_POST['envoyer']))
{
    if(!empty($nomP)){
        $_SESSION['nomP'] = $nomP;
    }

    if(!empty($objet)){
        $_SESSION['objet'] = $objet;
    }

    if(!empty($mail)){
        $_SESSION['mail']=$mail;
    }

    if(!empty($message)){
        $_SESSION['message']=$message;
    }

    /*echo "<br>Nom: ".$_SESSION['nomP'];
    echo "<br>Objet: ".$_SESSION['objet'];
    echo "<br>mail: ".$_SESSION['mail'];
    echo "<br>message: ".$_SESSION['message'];*/
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

And the same problem happen when I try to send informations via sessions vairables from contact.php to envoie_email.php.

envoie_email.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ob_start();?>
<html lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <title> E-COMMERCE </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/ordi.jpg" />
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/bootstrap.min.css?o2e784");
        <!--@import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/modern-business.css?o2e784");
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/site_global.css?o2e784");
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/style.css?o2e784");-->
        @import url("http://www.domicours.fr/sites/all/themes/venture_theme/css/responsive.css?o2e784");
        </style>

        <link href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

        <!-- CLOSE head -->
    </head>
    <a href="deconnexion.php" value="Deconnexion"/><img src="image/deconnexion.png" height="35px" width="110px" id="bouton"/></a>
        <br/><br/>
    <center><pre>Les cours d'informatique c'est des barres, ici on t'apprendra à créer des sites presque aussi beaux que celui-ci.</pre></center><br/>
        <p class="flotte">
            <center><a href="http://iut.nice.netspace.fr/g1_tpellero/ProjetSI/accueil.php"><img src="image/logo.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
        </p>
        <p style="line-height:50px;">
            <font size="10pt"> E-COMMERCE </font>
        </p></center>

    <body class="page page-id-390 page-template page-template-template-blog-php">
        <noscript>
            <div class="no-js-alert">Merci d'activer Javascript pour afficher correctement ce site web.</div>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
      <?php
        $destinataire='jeremy.bouville@etu.unice.fr';
        $message .= 'Pour : '.$destinataire."\n";
        $objet .= 'Objet : '.$_SESSION['objet']."\n\n";
        $message .= 'Contenu : '.$_SESSION['message']."\n";
        $headers = "From: ".$_SESSION['mail']."\r\n";

        mail($destinataire,$objet,$message,$headers);
       ?>
        <div id="texte">
            <center><p id="succes"><img id="logo_check" src="image/check.png" alt="Succès" height="500px" width="700px"/></p></center>
            <center><a href="accueil.php" value="Accueil" id="btnchiant"/><img src="image/accueil.png" height="70px" width="210px" id="btnchiant"/></a></center>
        </div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <footer id="copyright" style="padding: 10px;">
         <p><b> Created by BOUVILLE Jeremy - PELLERO Tom - G1 <b></p>
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jeremy.bouville.5?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="image/facebook.png" width="36px"></a>
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tom.pellero" target="_blank"><img src="image/facebook.png" width="36px"></a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
```

Can you help me please, I'm stuck with this problem since Saturday, and I can't continue my work if I don't resolve it.

Comment: Your action page is another page so your post will take you to that page without executing it on same page so your session variables are never set.

Comment: Thx man, it works, I don't know how but thx. I will let you know if I have another problem with it